# how to get UUID in swift didEnterRegion

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("didEnterRegion")


    let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "I came", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "My Information:\(region.identifier), major:\(beaconRegion.major!)/minor:\(beaconRegion.minor!)", arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber as NSNumber?;
    content.categoryIdentifier = "com.elonchan.localNotification"
    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: region.identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the notification.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request)
    userdefalut.set(nowTime, forKey: "lastDate_\(tempUUID_2)")
    userdefalut.synchronize()
    print(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)
}
```

CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-(name)")!, major:208, minor:56, identifier: "(name)(path)")

How Can I get UUID in didEnterRegion?
Please Help me..

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to cast `CLRegion` to `CLBeaconRegion`.  Like this in Swift 3:

```
let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion
```

Or this in Objective C:

```
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
```

Once you do that, you can access any fields on `CLBeaconRegion`:

Swift 3:

```
NSLog("My UUID: \(beaconRegion.proximityUUID)")
```

Objective C:

```
NSLog(@"My UUID: %@", beaconRegion.proximityUUID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion((region as! CLBeaconRegion))
    var r = (region as! CLBeaconRegion)
    self.sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("\(r.proximityUUID)")
    self.sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("\(r.identifier)")
}
```